# android ListView not getting updated after a modification to it's cursorLoader

Tags: android-fragments

I am new to android and java and working on an app that has a few remaining problems that I haven't resolved yet.
I have a main activity that is a viewPager, with each page being a fragment. If the 4 fragments 3 are extended from ListFragments and one from PreferencesFragment. 
The ListFragments have CursorAdapters to get data to and from SQLite databases through providers. 
I am able to get data into the database, insert, modify and query the data correctly and fill the list views ok. 
My preference setting are to choose different ways of viewing the data in the database. 
Not knowing how to do this, I have implemented a process where I modify the cursorLoader query to the provider with a number of different choices of the "WHERE" clause. I have worked out the logic for the preferences as they exist now, implemented the code but had some difficulty finding what to try to trigger the refresh of the ListView. 
Since the "dataset" hasn't really changed, no trigger can come from there, plus that would just use the same cursor as it currently exists to run the query again and return the same results (or be smart enough to know that it doesn't need to run). 
On Stack Overflow I did find a couple of references to a similar implementation that suggested reStarting the cursor loader, which would then on the reStart read the current values in the stored Preferences file, create a now modified WHERE clause that will show the sub-set of data as specified in the preference settings.
In testing the app now, even with the reStart of the cursorLoader, the ListView isn't getting refreshed. 
The only time I can get it to work right is restarting the app. If I stop the app and restart it, the new values are used and the ListView presents as the preferences dictate.

In looking through Stack Overflow and the Android site, I did find another set of APIs that might have been a more natural fit for what I am trying to do, namely the Filter APIs.

First question then would be, did I go in the wrong direction on how to control the "filtered" view of the datbase.   Is filtering a better approach and a recommended way of
doing what I am trying to do?
Second question would be related to the fragment lifecycle of my ListFragments to achieve this CursorLoader update.

Thanks for any input on the topic.
-Dan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to take what you posted and distill it into something a bit more concentrated. Imagine you're writing an e-mail to your coworker. It is very hard for us to read paragraphs and paragraphs and figure out what you want. Give a couple of sentences of background, explain what you need to, then state your question explicitly. That way, it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem here.
Two things, the way I am trying filtering is working and from what I have seen in the
Android development site, a reference there indicated that the filtering capability is
already implemented in the CursorAdapter, CursorLoader classes I am using.

When my preference settings changed, I did a reStart of the cursorLoader, but had restarted the wrong one.

Problem solved. Any input on is there a better way would be appreciated.
Regards, Dan